# Can the Templar Heal a Witch Doctor's minions?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

If I play a Witch Doctor with a couple of minions, will the Templar use Heal on minions even though the text says *you or the Templar*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, the Templar will only cast his Heal spell on the player or himself, as per the description.  I have not had him heal a minion or other ally regardless of them needing it.

I think this makes sense from a code implementation and game play point of view - it would be simpler to implement, while also avoiding frustration for Witch Doctor players if their pets got healed and then they died due to a lack of a Heal.